# how to fix Run time error 62 ''Input past end of file'

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a problem while trying to read a text file. Basically, the text file is comprised of blocks of information, between each block I have a blanck row. Hier is a sample of my text:

```
    FESTWERT FRAUS 
       LANGNAME "bla bla bla" 
       FUNKTION dfgg 
       EINHEIT_W "ü"
       WERT -9.2654122070312500
   END

    KENNFELD KFDWNWCSA 4 4
       LANGNAME "bla bla bla" 
       FUNKTION FGHK 
       EINHEIT_X "8/kl"
       EINHEIT_Y "bla"
       EINHEIT_W "bla"
       ST/X   1658.0000000000000000   987.0000000000000000   3698.0000000000000000           3520.0000000000000000   
       ST/Y   -30.0000000000000000
       WERT   22.0000000000000000   16.9870000000000000   10.3210000000000000    10.0000000000000000   
       ST/Y   0.0000000000000000
       WERT   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   
       ST/Y   45.2500000000000000
       WERT   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   
       ST/Y   21.0000000000000000
       WERT   22.0000000000000000   16.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   10.0000000000000000   
    END
```

actually I want to extract the numbers from these blocks. but I get this error: this is my Code:

```
  Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
 Dim ts As TextStream
 Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
 Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream

 strArray = Split(ts.ReadLine, Space(1), 2) ' Extrahieren, was in einer Zeile ist

If Len(Join(strArray, "")) <> 0 Then 
   If strArray(0) = "KENNFELD" Then  
     SWKNF = True
     ts.SkipLine
     ts.SkipLine
     ts.SkipLine
     ts.SkipLine
     ts.SkipLine
     wertkenfeld = strArray(1)
     strArray(1) = ""
   End If


   If strArray(0) = "END" Then werden
     If SWKNFL = True Then 
      For P = 0 To X - 1
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Test_DCML_G (XValue,Wert,name) VALUES ('" & Stx(P) & "','" & wert(P) & "','" & wertkenfeld & "');")
      Next P
     End If
     SWKNF = False
     SWKNFL = False
     Erase Warray
     X = 0
     W = 0
     Erase Yarray
     Erase Xarray
     Erase Stx
     Erase wert
     ts.SkipLine ' I get the error in this line
   End If
.....
```

Would you please help me to solve this problem?
Thank you so much

Comment: what if you remove this line with error? when calling this line you could be probably at the end of text file and `SkipLine` could be not allowed as there is nowhere to skip to.

Answer (score 2):

When you reach the last END of the file, a skip or read takes you beyond then end of the file.

I suggest you, as a **general rule**, if you need to skip or read lines to check EOF before moving (both for text files or recordset).
You can also use a loop with a condition in which you test if EOF has not been reached or the desired line has been found.

The first chunk in which you skip lines could be written as

```
  strReadLine = ""
  do while not ts.AtEndOfStream and not (strReadLine LIKE "ST/*")
    strReadLine = ts.readline
  loop
```

Bye